# Is it possible to get a name from Facebook's API using an email?

Tags: facebook

Like the title says, if I have e-mail address, can I retrieve the person's name using the Facebook API?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not retrieve a user's name from their email using the Facebook API.

All values that end in a * can be used to search for users. They are uid, name, and username.

However, if you get the user to manually authorize a facebook application that you create then you will be able to access the user's UID and you can use that to get their name.